# user update profile for custom code

Tags: php, themes, css, html, sql

I've added this code snippet to my functions.php

```
//hooks
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );

function Add_user_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <h3 class="sizeShapeH3">Select Chapters</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="dropdown" >MPF Chapters </label></th>
            <td>
            <?php 

                $topselected= get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID );  
            ?>

           <select name="user_top" id="user_top">
            <option value="MPF Pune Central:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune Central:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune Central:</option>
            <option value="MPF Pune East:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune East:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune East:</option>
            <option value="MPF Pune West:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune West:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune West:</option>
            <option value="MPF Pune South:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune South:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune South:</option>
            <option value="MPF PCMC:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF PCMC:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF PCMC:</option>


        </select>

        </td>
    </tr>


</table>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );

function save_user_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    //save top
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_chapters', $_POST['user_chapters'] );

    }
```

Now I see the chapter dropdown list at the user profile. but it is not saved when I change the user chapter. Eg: from the above list if I select **MPF Pune East** and press the button Update Profile then again I see **MPF Pune Central** as default. Seems it is not get saved when we click Update Profile button. do we have to something else to get it saved?

Comment: Can you reformat your code so it will be readable

Comment: please sir you can check now

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see

`$topselected= get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID );` ,

here you are using "**user_top**" as the meta_key but while updating you are using "**user_chapter**"

`update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_chapters', $_POST['user_chapters'] );`

Whatever `name` you are providing in `<select name="user_top" id="user_top">`, should be used in `$_POST['']`

So here you are using "**user_top**" as your select name, so it will be `$_POST['user_top']`

Comment: so can i replace "user_top" to "user_chapter"

Comment: $topselected= get_the_author_meta( "user_chapter", $user->ID );

Comment: yes you can do.. but whatever you are using.. use common in both the place

Comment: my meta_key is ..user_chapter_selected and i am using this format . update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_chapters', $_POST['user_chapter_selected'] );  $topselected= get_the_author_meta( 'user_chapter_selected', $user->ID );... but not working..same problem

Comment: and one more thing is my meta_key in wp_usermeta table not in wp_user table...

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: can i use  this ...    <select name="user_top" id="user_chapter_selected">

Comment: please any update sir.......

Comment: If you are using <select name="user_top" id="user_chapter_selected"> then make sure you are using `$_POST['user_top']` in `update_usermeta()` and it should be like `update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_chapters', $_POST['user_top'] );`